# text files clustering

Tags: java

i have text files as shown below

ex:

file 1:

```
       yamaha
       gladiator 
       bike
```

file 2:

```
       bajaj 
       pulsar
       bike
```

file 3:

```
       yamaha 
       gladiator
       india
```

i have to read these file indivisually and create clusters. means to say, from above ex, file 1 and file 3 are similar and will create one cluster. i want atleast a single word to be matched between two files to make a cluster. so finally i have to get two clusters from above ex as 
1: yamaha and 2: bajaj. pls help me with this....

Comment: What have you done already? Have you thought about an algorithm? Where do you have problems?

Comment: What is the exact definition of "similar" in this context?  If I have two arbitrary files, how do I decide if they're similar or not?  Is it symmetric (probably), transitive (probably not)?  Once you've defined the algorithm, implementing it will likely be quite simple.

Comment: if i have 3 text files as  i have given in ex... and among those 2 files will have at least one word matching among them. so it becomes one cluster.

Comment: pls soneone answer me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you simply need to read each file into a `Set<String>` of words and then looking for intersections to build your clusters. That could be achieved, for example, by building a map of words to a count of occurrences (`Map<String, Integer>`) or a map of words to a set of filenames (`Map<String, Set<String>>`).

Not sure where you second example cluster comes from as "bajaj" only exists in file 2.

**EDIT:** based on request to explain how Maps and Sets work

Instantiating a Map that maps strings (the word) to a set of filenames:

```
Map<String, Set<String>> wordsToFilenames = new HashMap<String, Set<String>>();
```

Adding a word found in a filename to this (assume we've read in a word from the file into the word variable and have the filename in a filename variable, both Strings):

```
Set<String> filenamesForWord;

if (wordsToFilenames.containsKey(word)) {
    filenamesForWord = wordsToFilenames.get(word);
}
else {
    filenamesForWord = new HashSet<String>();
    wordsToFilenames.put(word, filenamesForWord);
}

filenamesForWord.add(filename);
```

Comment: Do you know how to read text files? Have you ever used Java's collection classes?

Comment: ya i know how to read files. but i dont know how to add it to a "Map". i have never used it...

Comment: Best you read up on Java's collection classes: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html

Comment: @ john: can u please show me an example of using Map<String,Set<String>>

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the [naïve Bayesian classifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier) which does quite well in document classification. For other algorithms, try googling [text classification algorithm](http://www.google.fr/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=text%20classification%20algorithms).